# gulp error command not found

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm-install

sudo npm install gulp-cli -g

npm init
npm install gulp --save-dev

npm install browser-sync --save-dev // I added this file later, read documentation

I checked package.json which shows gulp too.
made gulp.js file as per documentation

Gulp is installed checked, npm ls. please find screen shot below
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn3w1.png

Please check below screenshot for gulp error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeAns.png

Comment: Execute `npm link` command and then try with your command which is currently throwing the error

Comment: Vipins-Air:site vipingupta$ npm link .                                                                                 
npm WARN site@1.0.0 No description
/Users/vipingupta/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/site -> /Users/vipingupta/Desktop/Sites/site

Comment: Okay.. Do you receive the `gulp: command not found` error now?

Comment: yes, it didn't work for me. I don't know everything is correct as per documentation

Comment: You can always install gulp globally or run it directly from node_modules.

Comment: yes, but its giving errors, command not find

Comment: @Skumar In windows, in such cases, I use to set the path variable to point to `AppData/Roaming/npm` by editing the `Environment Variables` in `System Properties`, I assume you're in linux environment, Can you please try doing the same in linux way?

Comment: @DavidR I am on Mac

Comment: Just google `mac set environment variable` and you will find the steps to add a new environment variable.

Comment: @DavidR http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.WTEWNxPyv-a. I am following this